# Does the Transporter Perk affects Throwing bags of corpses further aswell?

Tags: payday-2

The Enforcer tree has a perk called "Transporter"

> Transporter - Basic (1 SP/$4500): You move faster when carrying bags. 
>   Ace (3 SP/$12,500): You can throw bags further.

Does it affects the bodies put in a bag by players with a "Cleaner" perk, from the ghost tree?

> Cleaner - Basic (1 SP/$23,500): You deal additional damage against special enemies. 
>   Ace (3 SP/$69,500): You can bag and throw corpses.

Comment: If you have the cleaner perk we could maybe try this out later when I get home from work, because i have the transporter perk.

Comment: I would imagine it does a little bit, but I'm not certain. Transporter ace is nice to have anyway so you can throw lighter bags like money or coke rather far. However, heavier bags like gold aren't thrown very far still. So I imagine a body bag would behave much like a bag of gold in that you could probably throw it with transporter, but not very far.

Comment: It just says "bags" in the description, so why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - the transport perk when aced increases your throw distance by 50% as detailed on the [PD2 skills calculator](http://pd2skills.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Gameplay-wise, as a note, the difference between Transporter Aced and non Aced in regards to throwing body bags are relatively the same, so what you'll see on the screen will have no visible difference.  The distance you can throw body bags will still be extremely limited, since the game considers them as heavy items. Light items, such as cocaine and jewelry can be thrown farther and having Transporter Aced will make your throwing differences immediately noticable.